# Чем заменить оконную функцию в clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

Есть таблица в Clickhouse

```
id name click
11 dir  null
10 dir  123
9  ya   null
8  vk   null
7  ok   456
6  vk   null
```

надо заполнить null предыдущим значением и получить

```
id name click
-- 11 dir  null этой записи не должно быть
10 dir  123
9  ya   123
8  vk   123
7  ok   456
6  vk   456
```

Оконных функций в CH нет, можно что-то еще придумать?

Comment: Что такое "предыдущее значение"? Дайте чёткий критерий. Ближайшее бОльшее id? или строго на единицу больше? или есть иные критерии?

Answer (score 0):

По формальному критерию:

```
UPDATE table
SET click = ( SELECT t1.click
              FROM table t1
              WHERE t1.id > id
              ORDER BY t1.id
              LIMIT 1 );

DELETE FROM table
WHERE click IS NULL;
```